# "autocorrelation" of nominal variable

Tags: autocorrelation, multinomial-distribution, categorical-data

I have data on patients attendance of a series of sessions of counseling. At each session, a patient could be A, S or D. Each patient has data for 12 sessions, and there are ~100 patients.

I am interested in how the variables are 'autocorrelate'. I could just make 3x3 tables of (e.g.) time 1 vs. time 2, time 1 vs. 3, time 2 vs. 3, etc. but I am curious if there is something more sophisticated.

Googling this revealed some measures for spatial autocorrelation, e.g join-counts, but nothng specifically for temporal autocorrelation. I could also try to adapt the join counts to temporal data, but, again, am curious if someone has done this already.

I have access to R and SAS packages

Comment: See [markov-chain](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=markov+chain) questions/answers on this site.

Comment: Thanks @AndyW , I hadn't thought of that, but it's clearly a good idea.

Comment: I'm sure glad you didn't state that the patients could be S, A or D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One other thing to consider, besides markov-chain is sequence analysis / mining. There are several really good packages in R:

[TraMineR](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TraMineR/) which has the following very good docs:

- [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=6&ved=0CF4QFjAF&url=http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i04/paper&ei=3WKPT6qrPNP6ggfB6NTQBA&usg=AFQjCNEzfp-OCTMYOee2qUzQOE2HoVJHyQ)
- [here](http://mephisto.unige.ch/pub/TraMineR/doc/TraMineR-Users-Guide.pdf)

There is also that package [arulesSequence](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Sequence_Mining/SPADE).